# How to debug silverlight performance problems, data grid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I have a Silverlight navigation application, that for some reason when showing a data grid it consumes the entire processor...

For instance: [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvh2A.png)
[image: Check image here]

I do not know why it is doing this, it shouldnt be refreshing the grid, if I put a breakpoint on PropertyChanged, there are no properties changing...

**More Info**

I have tracked this down to showing a control that is showing a scroll bar (TreeView, DataGrid) when this is shown, the processor tries to reach the maximum framerate allowed (60) and clogs the CPU... I can turn this down, but the point is that it should not constantly be trying to reach this rate, it normally only refreshes the UI when something changes, but now it doing it when a scroll bar is presented!! What is going on here?

Has anyone got any ideas on how to go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Metro example theme for Silverlight there is a bug where if you are using the BusyIndicator along with having a dropshadow on the main frame CPU usage goes to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply pressing the Pause button in Visual Studion then examining the call stack on each thread.  If its something your code is doing you'll find some of your code running on at least one of the threads.  Going up the stack should then get you to either some horrible loop that shouldn't be happening or an event which for some other reason keeps firing.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I tried this but each thread does not appear to be running any .NET code, I cannot find any thread that will give me a call stack to dive in to...

Comment: @James: Do you get the same problem when using another browser like IE?

Comment: Yes the same issue occurs when using IE9.